# How should I deal with a boss who shouts at me everyday for things I am not responsible for?

Tags: resignation, culture, unprofessional-behavior

My boss relies heavily on me for all her daily tasks, especially since a lot of her staff have resigned and left. So I am now doing the job of three people in addition to my own duties (which is a LOT) and hiring replacement staff (from selecting resumes to scheduling and conducting interviews - and then coordinating hire, training and assignments). This excludes any impromptu work my boss may demand from me. (I work in healthcare.)

Having so much work is not a problem - I am a very good multi-tasker and I love a fast paced environment - but what bothers me is that she does not respect me at all (let alone appreciate my good work).

- She never allows me to attend any managerial training, but shouts at me if I do not follow basic managerial policies.
- She shouts at me if a kitchen cabinet is not clean (I ended up cleaning and scrubbing it myself) or if someone's desk is not clean
- She shouts at me when someone didn't answer the phone within three rings.
- She forces me to use my personal phone for work (and give out my cell number to patients), demands that I answer her calls after hours, and even run her personal errands.
- Just yesterday she made a personal remark: she complimented me on my shoes and asked what my shoe size is so she could borrow my shoes. When I told her my size (being way taller than her, my shoe size is bigger than her) she exclaimed "oh my God!" and took a step back. I felt so offended.

I have started to feel more disconnected with each passing day. I am actively looking for a job and almost landed one, but since I need work sponsorship the offer was rescinded. (Needless to say I was devastated!)

I have a clinical background from my home country and completed my Masters with honors from a very reputed university in the US. Having to face such experiences on a daily basis is not only shocking, but also very intoxicating. I am now so fed up that I am planning to just quit (my contract is at-will).

Please note speaking up is NOT an option because I am not ready to face the consequences. It would simply mean personally and cordially inviting hell to my doorstep. She knows due to my sponsorship issues, I have nowhere to go and so she can treat me however she wants.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deal with rude senior after being shouted at?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17968/how-to-deal-with-rude-senior-after-being-shouted-at) See also: [My boss slapped me over a calculation error](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/my-boss-slapped-me-over-a-calculation-error)

Comment: I don't see how you can change her behavior since you can't quit, are probably afraid to give feedback and indicate when you've been offended, so other than tell you to just ignore her, what else do you expect? This is such a grim description it's as if you intended to exclude any possible solution.

Comment: Unfortunately this is exactly the situation. I can only think of 1 reasonable explanation - bad luck. Other supervisors (who quit) committed several mistakes in their work and even though I reported to the boss to talk to them, she never did. She simply told me to check behind them or do the work myself.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: I have been hunting for a job for more than 6 months now. Visa is the only problem. Now my question is- is this behavior from a boss normal (or acceptable), and how badly will any future employers take the gap in my resume if I quit without another job.

Comment: "I have nowhere to go and so she can treat me however she wants" - this should never be the case so I really don't understand why "speaking up is NOT an option". If you speak up and she fires you, where does that leave HER? If you are already doing the work of others (who presumably quit for the same reason) I would say you do have some bargaining power to stop her acting like she does. Does she act this way to others out of interest?

Comment: The moment I read the summary, I had an answer.  Don't deal with a boss who shouts at you.  I don't care why she shouts at you.  A boss shouting at you is simply rude, unprofessional and unbecoming.  I would deal with it by working somewhere else, which is what you are trying to do.